# onClick event not working , because of nested tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

onClick event not working , I have this html code

```html
<a class='list-group-item media' href='#'>
    <div class='media-body'>
        <div class='pull-left'>
            <div class='lg-item-heading'></div>
            <small class='lg-item-text'></small>
        </div>
        <div class='pull-right'>
            <div class='lg-item-heading'>
                <button onClick='alert("Is it working??")' class='btn bg-danger pv20 text-white fw600'>
                    <i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

The button element has -> onClick='alert("Is it working??")' , however not working

I guess it's because of the nested elements , it fires on the outer element `<a>` not on the inner element `<button>` , how to handle this issue ??

as soon as I hover with my mouse on the inner element `<button>` - the browser tells me that I'm hovering on `<a>` tag and in clicking will redirect me to a specific URL

Comment: It works fine for me, try **giving some content to the button**. As of now its a button with hardly any width or height - `<button onClick='alert("Is it working??")'><i></i> Click</button>`. Even if it works `<button>` within an `<a>` is **not a valid HTML structure**

Comment: button inside of a link seems like invalid html to me

Comment: did you try event.preventDefault in your js/jquery/whatever on your anchor ?

Comment: works fine for me in safari 10.0.3 and in chrome 59

Comment: Works fine in the snippet

Comment: [HTML Validator states:](https://validator.w3.org) "Error: The element `button` must not appear as a descendant of the `a` element."

Comment: No , the css files , makes <a> tag big and <button> inside it , if you tested the html only , it will work with you I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `stopPropagation()` from your button. That'll prevent it from bubbling up to your `<a>` element.

```js
function onAnchorClick(e) {
  console.log('Anchor clicked');
}

function onButtonClick(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('Is it working');
}

document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', onAnchorClick);
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
```

```html
<a class='list-group-item media' href='#'>
  <div class='media-body'>
    <div class='pull-left'>
      <div class='lg-item-heading'></div>
      <small class='lg-item-text'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='pull-right'>
      <div class='lg-item-heading'>
        <button class='btn bg-danger pv20 text-white fw600'>
          <i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'>Something</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

I also rearranged the code and set the event with an `addEventListener` instead, as you can't really get the event object you need in order to call `stopPropagation()`.

That said, having a button inside of an anchor isn't a good idea. If you want a link that looks like a button, you should just style the anchor to look like a button. Otherwise, there is no reason to wrap it in an anchor (especially in this example), so you should just remove the anchor.